# How to pass data from bindingsource to an object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform form which is using a bindingsource as data source to a custom object. How do assign data from bindingsource to my object. So that I can pass that object as a parameter in a function C#

```
     class Employee: EntityBase
     {
          public string EmployeeID
          { 
            get { return _EmployeeID; }
            set
            {
               if (Equals(value, _EmployeeID)) return;
              _EmployeeID = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged(() => EmployeeID);
           }
     }
```

My Save button look like this

```
      private void RbBtSave_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
      {
        HRConstant URI = new HRConstant();
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new   Uri(URI.ClientHtt()) };
        HREmployeeTrans HREmployeeTrans = new HREmployeeTrans();
        //this.hREmployeeBindingSource.AddNew();
        Employee VarEmployee = new Employee();
        VarEmployee = (Employee)EmployeeBindingSource.AddNew();
        //MessageBox.Show(VarEmployee.EmployeeID);
        HREmployeeTrans.CreateEmployees(client, VarHREmployee);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by creating an instance of an object in the form load event and  initalize the bindingsource with the object

```
HREmployee VarHREmployee= new HREmployee();
EmployeeBindingSource.datasource=VarHREmployee;
```